# Return a list from column values in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Hello Stack Overflow community!

Using Python, I would like to build a function that takes a row, then returns a new column containing a list with the values from each column in that row. Here's my example--

```
+--------+--------+-------+
| first  | second | third |
+--------+--------+-------+
| monkey | banana | time  |
| banana | monkey | time  |
| time   | monkey | time  |
+--------+--------+-------+
```

What I'd like to return is:

```
+--------+--------+-------+----------------------------+
| first  | second | third |            list            |
+--------+--------+-------+----------------------------+
| monkey | banana | time  | ['monkey','banana','time'] |
| banana | monkey | time  | ['banana','monkey','time'] |
| time   | monkey | time  | ['time','monkey','time']   |
+--------+--------+-------+----------------------------+
```

I've tried this function (for a dataframe with 14 columns), but it did not work:

```
def return_list_for_importance_rank(row):
        row_list = []
        my_list = [row.first, row.second, row.third, row.fourth, row.fifth, row.sixth, row.seventh, row.eighth, row.ninth, row.tenth, row.eleventh, row.twelfth, row.thirteenth, row.fourteenth]
        row_list.append(my_list)
        return row_list

importance_rank["full"] = df.apply(lambda x: return_list_for_importance_rank(x),axis=1)
```

Which returned this:

```
<bound method NDFrame.first of first         None\nsecond        None\nthird         None\nfourth        None\nfifth         None\nsixth         None\nseventh       None\neighth        None\nninth         None\ntenth         None\neleventh      None\ntwelfth       None\nthirteenth    None\nfourteenth    None\nfull          None\n
```

In the "Full" column of every row.

Comment: Use, `df['list'] = df.agg(list, axis=1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
df['list'] = df.to_numpy().tolist()
```

Output:

```
    first  second third                    list
0  monkey  banana  time  [monkey, banana, time]
1  banana  monkey  time  [banana, monkey, time]
2    time  monkey  time    [time, monkey, time]
```